# What is Research 10+ doing?

Tags: star-trek-birth-of-the-federation

Hello dear ST or strategy fans :)

I play this game only occasionally and thus am not fully aware of everything.

Recently I've read a guide.

From the guide a few questions evolved, where one is this.
Here is a cite from the guide that made me question this myself. However and btw when I review my games always wondered about it :)

```
When [...] your research nearing future tech 1 (11 in each category)
```

This implies to me that Calladice (the writer) has reasearched everything to 10.

The question or tldr; is:

I looked at for example: Research - Object databse - Biotechnology - (10) Siliko Biotechnology
You can see there that Biotechnology 10 doesn't enable new structures or ships.

1. So generally and by itself what is the point of researching
   something to 10 if it's not for some ship?
2. Btw: Which advantages do give "Future Tech1" like Bio 11 (or even
   12)** ?

Thanks in advance. I tried to search for an answer before, but it didn't reach me.

**ps: I am aware of Energytechnology increasing Shield Generator's capacity by 50/techlevel.